# Debugging node with node-inspector CORS issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, cors, node-inspector

I am trying to debug an issue with Node & Express. I am debugging with node-inspector. When I run my node app without debugging my jQuery HTTP requests work fine but when I run the node app with node-inspector I get

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource

How can I solve this or work around it?

I have tried to enable cors on the node app but it doesn't help.

Comment: Where do you see the error? Is it in Node Inspector? What is the URL of the request that was rejected because of CORS?

Comment: Have you tried installing cors npm module and bundling it to app?
`npm install cors --save` and then in main server code `app.use(cors());` where app is `var app = express();`.

Comment: Thanks Rafal but I think I solved it over a year ago. :)

Comment: @SamLeach Then it would be nice of you to write your solution for others who come across similar issue...

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a real headache. I remember facing something this some time back! It's the CORS thing that restricts web pages from making calls to a different domain. But hang on, you said you already tried enabling CORS in your NODE app, right?

Alright, lets dive a bit deeper:

First up, we need to make sure, we've got the CORS stuff set up properly in Express. I usually do it with the `cors` npm package, like so:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
```

Make sure you've popped app.use(cors()); right before any routes. Sometimes the order can mess things up!

Also, have you checked if the nde-inspector isn't running on the same aport as your app? That tipped me up once. They should have different ports or things get a bit wonky.

Oh and here's another weird one: browser extensions. Some of them mess with CORS headers. Maybe give it a shot and disbale a few non-essential ones to see if that helps.

Lastly, double check the client side, especially those jQuery requests. Might be something funky going on with headers or how it's making those cross-origin requests.

If these tricks don't do the job, shoot over some more details about your setup. The more we know, the faster we can nail down this problem.

Hang in there and happy debugging! Catch you later!